# JQuery and Prototype.js conflict in using dataTable.js

Tags: jquery, datatable, prototypejs

I am having jQuery and protype.js included in my project. Now I want to apply dataTable on one table. I have included dataTable.js and initiate dataTable as-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#sortable_mappedTable').DataTable();
</script>
```

But its giving me an error like-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined.    prototype_1_6.js:596
```

Any guess whats happening here?

Comment: Provide full code among with your HTML. Have you made sure that your table has a `<thead>..</thead>` and a `<tbody>..</tbody>`? Also made sure that your asSorting is properly defined, like for example so: `"asSorting": [0, 'asc']` not `"asSorting": [[0, 'asc']]`

Comment: it looks like you are using PrototypeJS 1.6, Are you using Magento, if not can you upgrade to 1.7.2 (released April 2014) that might resolve the problem

Comment: @urbz Thanks. It works with <thead> and <tbody>